# calculating the integral $\int x^{-2} e^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus

How can I calculate the integral $\int x^{-2} e^{-x^2}dx$.
Is it possible to calculate? I think it is impossible.

Comment: It's impossible to represent the result by means of "elementary" functions, however using partial integration one can deduce a representation involving the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) $\mathrm{erf}$, for which there are many rapidly converging approximations.

Comment: Ok AlexR. Thanks. So it is impossible to find an elementary function.

Comment: By the usual notion of elementary function, yes. Only a sequence of elementary functions can be given which converges to the desired function.

Answer (score 4):

Integrate by parts.  $u=e^{-x^2}$ and $dv=x^{-2}dx$.
$$
\int x^{-2}e^{-x^2}=-x^{-1}e^{-x^2}-2\int e^{-x^2}dx=-x^{-1}e^{-x^2}-\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}(x)
$$

Comment: erf(x) is the error function. but I have another question. Can we find Exact answer?

Comment: @hamed: Gaffney already gave an exact answer in terms of `Erf`.

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat impossible to compute the integrand.  Based on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%5E%28-2%29e%5E%28-x%5E%282%29%29), you get the following expression:

$$\int x^{-2}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx = -\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}x\,\mathrm{erf}(x) + e^{-x^2}}{x} + \mbox{C}$$

Comment: I'm not really sure of your first sentence. Nonelementary functions are just as valid as elementary ones.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating by parts you'll get the general expression
$$
\int x^{-2}e^{-x^2}=-x^{-1}e^{-x^2}-2\int e^{-x^2}dx
$$
but if you want to evaluate the integral over $[-\infty,+\infty]$, by the gaussian integral the result is $-2 \sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: That would be surprising, as the integrand is always positive.  I think the issue is that the integral diverges at zero.

Comment: You're right, it's wrong, but where's the mistake? The use of the error function is essentially I imagine

Comment: Well, suppose I told you that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{-2} = -x^{-1}|_{-\infty}^\infty = 0$.  You can't do this when the thing you're integrating isn't defined everywhere.

Comment: What a mistake! the function isn't defined in $(0,0)$. Forget it!